# Getting my actual movie cover data to render instead of just the hash in vue.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

ok so here is what I am running into for my final project for my class I am building an app that is like a movie bucket list using a bunch of hard coded data because I couldn’t find an api that would cooperate so I can get my watchlist to render but it only renders as a hash not with the box art or anything like that. This is my JavaScript and HTML using vue.js any help would be massively appreciated.

this is all that will render

[image]

```
`<template>
  <div class="list">
    <div v-for="list in lists" v-bind:key="list.id">
      <i>{{ list }}</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      list: [],
      lists: [],
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    this.indexLists();
  },
  methods: {
    indexLists: function () {
      axios.get("/lists").then((response) => {
        this.lists = response.data;
        console.log("list", response.data);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
`
```

Comment: Your problem is your database does not contain the data you would like to see rendered in your app. Which is not a programming error. In other words, your code runs flawlessly. It displays what you told it to display. The problem is you told it to display something else than what you want to see.

Comment: Ok so what I am gathering is that something needs to change to render my list as my movie data (which contains like the physical artwork and stuff about the movie) any idea on what I can change to render that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create a folder and put all the movie posters in there, name them `poster-movie_id.png` e.g. `poster-3.png` then in your code

```
<template>
  <div class="list">
    <div v-for="list in lists" v-bind:key="list.id">
        <img src="images/posters/poster-{{ list.movie_id }}.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try in the morning. I really appreciate the help it's my final project before I graduate next Thursday and I've been pulling what little hair that I have left out trying to figure this out lol.